# image1.visible=true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am sending an email and it takes a few seconds to collect data, format it, verify it, and send it, so for user interaction I have placed a gif image of a progess bar for user to wait,.

I have made this image visible property to false in design mode, now i want to show this image when user clicks send email and hide it when image successfully sent. I have written email sending code and it works fine, and at top of that I wrote `image1.visible=true` and at bottom of email sending code I `image1.visible=false` and displayed email sent successfully in a label.

However, image is not displaying. Please help or any alternative?

Comment: Are you expecting to show the image after the postback? Also please post the code.

Comment: can you explain more, are you trying to send image in email body? And post your code

Comment: This is an example of why too much abstraction is a bad thing. You get situations where people take a paradigm of an ASP.NET page and think it carries over to an email. Wow.

Comment: i am sending email it takes few seconds to collect data format it verify it and send it, so for user interaction i have placed a gif image of a progess bar for user to wait, i have made this image visible property to false in design mode, now i want to show this image when user clicks send email and hide it when image successfully sent, i have wrote email sending code it works fine, and at top of that i wrote **image1.visible=true** and at bottom of email sending code i **image1.visible=false** and displayed email sent successfully in a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommended you to use UpdateProgress. here is the sample:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upchk1">
    <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" />
         //you can even specify button which is outside of UpdatePanel.
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Check!" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
       <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upchk1">
          <ProgressTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="Style/spinner.gif" runat="server" />&nbsp;Checking...
          </ProgressTemplate>
      </asp:UpdateProgress>
    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

so, UpdateProgress's image (Image1) only will be visible while completing the task.

Comment: your welcome. please make it as answer if it worked for you, so that other can get.